# Image domain vs. subdomain

Tags: image, dns, cross-domain

I'm nearing end of development of a site, and am offloading images, scripts and fonts to a second server pool. Currently, the static pool is io.mydomain.com and the site itself is mydomain.com (www.* redirects to naked domain).

It's been well documented* that using a separate DNS lookup for static assets improves performance as it doubles concurrent asset downloads, but I'm trying to find the highest performance method of achieving this?

My question is this: from a DNS perspective, is it better to use a subdomain (TLD lookup, domain lookup, subdomain lookup), like Apple does (images.apple.com), or a separate domain (TLD lookup and domain lookup) like Yahoo and Microsoft do (yimg.com and c.s-microsoft.com)? Is there much of a difference between the two or is it negligible?

*https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that nothing is cached, there would be a infinitesimally small improvement brought about by having the same top level domain.

For the same top level domain queries the queries would go something like

1. query root servers for .com. name servers
2. query .com. name servers for .example.com. name servers.
3. query .example.com. name servers for www.example.com
4. query .example.com. (cached address) name servers for io.example.com.

For separate domains it would be

1. query root servers for .com. name servers
2. query .com. name servers for .example.com. name servers.
3. query .example.com. name servers for www.example.com
4. query .com.(cached address) name servers for .xmpl.com. name servers.
5. query .xmpl.com. name servers for io.xmpl.com

Once that first query was made - as long as you hadn't set incredibly short expiry - the client would never need to look them up again.

At the very best, you *might* shave a millisecond from the very first query. After that it changes nothing.

It isn't even remotely worth thinking about! there are so many other places where you will transiently loose that sort of time.

Comment: Thanks so much, Michael. Great answer. Everything is cached, optimized, behind a CDN and each server has about 8 ISP's which are speed optimized, and apache itself has been stripped down to the absolute bare minimum (10 modules total, down from 30 or 40 by default). I'm down to between 0.9s and 1.1s depending on load, and I'm trying to squeeze every little bit of time.

Thanks again!